# DocType is not showing in the rendered output from JSF

Tags: jquery, jsf, richfaces, facelets

I am trying into integrate JSF1.2, Richfaces 3.3.0 GA, Facelets1.1 and JQuery. The issue i am facing is the rendered output is starting from  i.e its missing the Doc type and HTML Tag.

For example

```
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"  
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"><ui:composition>
<head>  </head> <body>  kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk   </body> </ui:composition></html>
```

and the rendered output is

---

```
<head> <script src="/wmat/a4j/g/3_3_0.GA/org/ajax4jsf/framework.pack.js.faces" type="text/javascript"></script><script src="/wmat/a4j/g/3_3_0.GA/org/richfaces/ui.pack.js.faces" type="text/javascript"></script><link class="component" href="/wmat/a4j/s/3_3_0.GAorg/richfaces/renderkit/html/css/basic_both.xcss/DATB/eAFrvajdHLp8hjQAEgwDtA__.faces" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /><link class="component" href="/wmat/a4j/s/3_3_0.GAorg/richfaces/renderkit/html/css/extended_both.xcss/DATB/eAFrvajdHLp8hjQAEgwDtA__.faces" media="rich-extended-skinning" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /><link class="component" href="/wmat/a4j/s/3_3_0.GA/org/richfaces/skin.xcss/DATB/eAFrvajdHLp8hjQAEgwDtA__.faces" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /><script type="text/javascript">window.RICH_FACES_EXTENDED_SKINNING_ON=true;</script></head> <body> kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk</body></html>
```

I dont know why its not showing the `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>` Tags in the rendered output.

Jquery Components are not working because of this issue.

Can anybody please help me to sort it out? Not sure what I am missing in this

In the ice face forum i can see the same issue reported but iceface provides a direct solution for this. Please check **[this](http://www.icefaces.org/JForum/posts/list/15782.page)** link for more details

Thanks in Advance
Jobin

Answer (score 3):

Get rid of those `<ui:composition>` tags, they do not belong in the "master template". They belong in the include template files. When used in include files, only their content will be parsed and everything outside those tags will be ignored, which is what you're now seeing.

Comment: Hi BalusC,  It worked :) Thank you for the help.. So <ui:composition> should use only when we have a template?

Comment: @Jobin - <ui:composition> tags are used in the template client - the page that uses the layout of the main template. <ui:composition> tags surround the whole content of your page, as BalusC said anything outside them gets ignored. Nested within are your <ui:define> tags, those identify what portions of your template you are overriding with custom page content.