# HTML doctype getting removed in JSF

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, facelets

My `<!DOCTYPE html>` declaration is getting removed from my JSF pages, and it's messing things up.

This same question has been asked a bunch of times:

[HTML doctype declaration in JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12358196/html-doctype-declaration-in-jsf)

[DocType is not showing in the rendered output from JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4763313/doctype-is-not-showing-in-the-rendered-output-from-jsf)

[JSF template: rendered page missing DOCTYPE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505219/jsf-template-rendered-page-missing-doctype)

Trouble is, [this Jira entry](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-2453) says the bug has been fixed. Apparently not. I'm using the most recent version:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0-m07</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0-m07</version>
    </dependency>
```

For reference, here are my pages:

test_layout.xhtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
<body>
    <ui:insert name="content"/>
</body>
</html>
```

test_content.xhtml:

```
<ui:composition 
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    template="test_layout.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="content">
        bunch 'o content
    </ui:define>

</ui:composition>
```

Anybody got a workaround?

Comment: not the answer to your question, but at the moment i wouldn't use JSF 2.2 yet. it is still under development and not yet released. did you try with the latest 2.1.x version?

Comment: @fischermatte: we need people trying beta's/pre-releases to test things...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded to 2.2.0-m08 and the problem went away.

Comment: It seem to be back with 2.2.14 or a view earlier patch levels. also it is present with 2.3.2 (latest beta).